# In place quick sort pseudo code?

Tags: sorting, quicksort, pseudocode

I'm trying to come up with a pseudocode description of the in-place version of quick-sort that is specialized to take an array as input and return that same array as output. In this version the array may have duplicate elements. (That is, the elements may not be unique).

Any suggestions on what the pseudo code would look like?

Comment: Is pseudocode for Java different than normal pseudocode?

Comment: @ChrisMartin sorry, pseudocode in general I meant!

Comment: I think http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quicksort has what you're looking for?

Comment: @ChrisMartin I think that might be it, but does it work with duplicate values like I described in my problem description? A bit new to these sorting algorithms, so please excuse the stupid questions!

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what ["weak order"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering) means in the summary.